# How to write a function for a variable name?

Tags: r

I have an object that is `st`

```
str(st)
List of 34
$ cell_ele    : num [1:2000, 1:1000] 999 999 ...
```

Now I want to write  a function

```
myfun <- function(var){
rt= st$var 
rt=raster(rt)
out <- writeRaster(rt, filename = "C:\\var_data")
                      }
```

`var` will be used twice , to be read and then to be part of the output file name

```
 myfun (cell_ele)
 Error in raster(matrix(data = rt)) : 
 error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 
'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

I tried it without the function and it worked fine. The problem is in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this command written inside the function's body:

```
rt= st$var
```

This will look for a column named **var** of the variable `st`. It will not substitute `var` with the contents of the variable given as an argument.

Instead, you should have written:

```
rt = st[var]
```

So please alter your function like so:

```
myfun <- function(var){
  rt= st[var]
  rt=raster(rt)
  out <- writeRaster(rt, filename = paste("C:\\", var, "_data", sep=""))
}
```

which will do the substitution and look for a column whose name is defined by the argument you are passing to the function. We are also using the function `paste`, since we want to have a variable name:

> **paste converts its arguments (via as.character) to character strings, and concatenates them (separating them by the string given by sep).** If the arguments are vectors, they are concatenated term-by-term to give a character vector result.

Also, you should pass a string argument:

```
myfun ("cell_ele")
```

> **The [[ form allows only a single element to be selected using integer or character indices, whereas [ allows indexing by vectors.** Note though that for a list or other recursive object, the index can be a vector and each element of the vector is applied in turn to the list, the selected component, the selected component of that component, and so on. The result is still a single element.
>
> **The form using $ applies to recursive objects such as lists and pairlists. It allows only a literal character string or a symbol as the index.** That is, the index is not computable: for cases where you need to evaluate an expression to find the index, use x[[expr]]. When $ is applied to a non-recursive object the result used to be always NULL: as from R 2.6.0 this is an error.

Comment: When you write rt <- st[var], var is substituted by your argument. When you want to access it through the `[]` operator, you should write rt = st["cell_ele"]

Comment: I would have thought the OP would want `[[` not `[`, but I'm not familiar with what `writeRaster` is expecting, so I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks.that worked.What about the name.the output is named `var` not the name I entered in the function

Comment: Hmm I didn't know you'd like a variable name. I have updated the answer to address the issue.